# Mapping over an object that is full of end points to an api using async

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

Hi I have an object that looks like this after I used async.map and ansync.mapValues to populate this object from my api which is an individual message type

```
messageType = {
    stationery: {
         designs: [endpoint, endpoint],
         paper: [endpoint]
        },
        envelope: {
         designs: [endpoint, endpoint, endpoint],
         paper: [endpoint, endpoint],
         seals: [endpoint],
         stamps: [endpoint]
        }
 }
```

My async function looks like this

```
let messageType = {
                    stationery: {
                        designs: [data.stationery.designs],
                        paper: [data.stationery.paper]
                     },
                    envelope: {
                         designs: [data.envelope.designs],
                         paper: [data.envelope.paper],
                         seals: [data.envelope.seals],
                         stamps: [data.envelope.stamps]
                      }
                    }
       //console.log(messageType)

       async.mapValues(messageType, (parentComponent, key, callback) => {
             async.mapValues(parentComponent, (childComponents, k, cb) => {
                   async.map(childComponents, (component, done) => {

                     done(null, {name: component})
              }, (e, r) => {
                  cb(e, r)
              })
              }, (err, res) => {
                 callback(err, res)
               })
              }, (error, results) => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))
         })
```

this returns me my object with all my endpoints, I need to make an ajax call that turns those endpoints into the data that comes from them, I made an API helpers function that looks like

API.get(endpoint, callback)

I've been stuck on this for a while and I feel like I'm close to reuturning the data instead of the endpoints, anyone know what I got to do to call all the endpoints in my object and populate my messagetype object with that?

Comment: can you paste the code for one of the endpoints? all of their APIs are the same? They do not take arguments other than a callback? Is the callback uniform with two parameters `(err, result)`?

Comment: yeah all the endpoints are just paths and the look the same just with different ids in there path an example endpoint looks like this '/component/idnumber'

Answer (score 0):

If you make a simple wrapper which turns you `API.get` from a function that takes a callback into one that returns a Promise …

```
import API from './api'

const get = url =>
  new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
    API.get(url, (err, res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)))
```

You can forget about all that `async` nonsense and use [tj/co](https://github.com/tj/co). Notice how the code looks almost identical to your first paste

```
co(function* () {
  return {
    stationery: {
      designs: yield get(data.stationery.designs),
      paper: yield get(data.stationery.paper)
    },
    envelope: {
      designs: yield get(data.envelope.designs),
      paper: yield get(data.envelope.paper),
      seals: yield get(data.envelope.seals),
      stamps: yield get(data.envelope.stamps)
    }
  }
}).then(message => {
  // use the message here
  // instead of containing urls, fetched data from the urls will be present
  console.log(message)
}, err => {
  // display errors here
  console.error(err.message, err)
})
```

--

**ps** you're misspelling *stationary*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()`, `Promise.all()`, `Array.prototype.concat()` to flatten returned array of promise values

```js
let messageType = {
  stationery: {
    designs: [1],
    paper: [2]
  },
  envelope: {
    designs: [3],
    paper: [4],
    seals: [5],
    stamps: [6]
  }
}

var promises = [];

Object.keys(messageType).forEach(type => 
  Object.keys(messageType[type]).forEach(endpoint =>
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // do asynchronous stuff
      setTimeout(() => {
        // var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // request.open(messageType[type][endpoint])
        // request.onload = () => resolve(request.response);
        // request.onerror = (e) => reject(e);
        // request.send();
        resolve(messageType[type][endpoint])
      }, Math.random() * 2500)
    }))
  )
);

Promise.all(promises)
.then(data => console.log([].concat.apply([], data)));
```